# Inheritance from a generic in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

I've look around and haven't see anyone else who is having this problem (though it might be I'm just searching the wrong terms). If I have a simple generic class like:

```
class Foo<S> {
    var values:[S]

    init(values:S...) {
        self.values = values
    }
```

}

and I want to create a subclass:

```
class Bar<S>: Foo<S> {
    override init(values:S...) {
        super.init(values: values)
    }
}
```

For the `Bar` class I get the error:

```
error: cannot convert value of type '[S]' to expected argument type '[_]'
```

Does anyone know if this is either expected before and how to fix this, or if this is a bug that should be reported?

Comment: This has indeed been answered before :) but the error message is not obvious. Inside the init method of class B, `values` is an *array* which cannot be passed as a *variable argument list.* You have to add another `init(values:[S])` method to the superclass.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes a lot of sense. I suspected I was missing something obvious. Thanks!